# acumatica fastfilter (inventory item search within sales order entry grid)

Tags: acumatica

Looking to 'exclude' the inventory item description but 'add' a custom field against the inventory item master (called model).
I thought I found where this is stored in the aspx of the screen but any changes I make don't seem to make a difference.
Does anyone know if fastfilters can be edited/altered to exclude/include different fields?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

FastFilter fields in Form/Detail inquiry grid are inclusive, you pick only the one you need, the others are excluded by default.

For an Inquiry Grid, modify the property FastFilterFields of the Grid element. The value is a comma separated list of the field names you want to use as fast filters:
[image]

For an Inquiry Grid inside a Selector popup window, select the RowTemplate Editor for the Selector and look for the FastFilterFields in the collapsible GridProperties section. If required, expirement with the FilterByAllFields property.
[image]